# Problem with scraping OP.GG website with node.js and cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm a beginner with node.js and cheerio and a little help would be awesome :D

I try to scrape the pubg.op.gg website to have two simple elements to show them in the console.
Here is my code:

```
var url = "https://pubg.op.gg/user/K1uu"
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cheerioAdv = require('cheerio-advanced-selectors');

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var playerName = $('.player-summary__name');
    var playerNameText = playerName.text();
    console.log(playerNameText);

    var playerRank = $('.ranked-stats__rating-point');
    var playerRankText = playerRank.text();
    console.log(playerRankText);   
})
```

[image: Image of values]

I  try to have something like this : "Kyuu - 1503"
No problem for the Kyuu value for playernickname but impossible to have the 1503 however the name of the div is correct !
Where is my problem ?

Thanks guys !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey and welcome to StackOverflow!

That website uses AJAX to fetch the ratings, so when the HTML is loaded the ratings are not available and the `ranked-stats__rating-point` class does not exist yet. If you check it with the browser's developer tools, you can see that it requests 3 additional URLs for the 3 different rating point (the only difference is the `queue_size` URL param).

https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/59fdce2bdf1b210001a9324d/ranked-stats?season=pc-2018-01&queue_size=1&mode=tpp
https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/59fdce2bdf1b210001a9324d/ranked-stats?season=pc-2018-01&queue_size=2&mode=tpp
https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/59fdce2bdf1b210001a9324d/ranked-stats?season=pc-2018-01&queue_size=4&mode=tpp

You should be able to request the first rating like this:

```
var url = "https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/59fdce2bdf1b210001a9324d/ranked-stats?season=pc-2018-01&queue_size=1&mode=tpp";
var request = require('request');

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(body);
  var score = jsonData['stats']['rating'];
  console.log(score);  // outputs "1520"
} );
```

However the username is not available from these endpoints, so you need to find another API endpoint for that if you want to fetch these for arbitrary usernames.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted !
Thanks korsosa, i will use my previous method for the playerName.
Have a good day.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the feedback! I marked it as "requires editing", because I believe the error symptoms should have been added by the author and it was not clear to me what error he is facing. After studying the triage help, I see that the button was misleading to me. Assigning it to a random editor was definitely not a good choice, as you don't know much about the error either, it should have been edited by the author. Thanks for highlighting this to me!

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 0):

Hi korsosa and thanks for your answer !
Yes, there is multiple elements with ranked-stats__rating-point for the name.

There is the result of your code :

var playerRankText = playerRank[1].text();
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Comment: True, as it turns out the scores are fetched with AJAX, so they are not available on the webpage initially. This is why the result is undefined - the `ranked-stats__rating-point` class does not yet exist in the result. I will update my answer shortly, sorry for misleading.